# Horizontal listview in android

Tags: android, listview

HI I am New to the Android.I parsed data from Xml file,now what i want is i have to show the parsed data  into a tabbed structure,which should be scrollable.

**My design should be like this:**

```
 Sports  Movies  International Technology ......
```

I looked for horizontal listview ,but i came to a conclusion that horizontal listview is not possible.So please give some idea how can i display this,also give some reference link to know about the UI deigns in android. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like HorizontalScrollView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jake Wharton's [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). You can get the project from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)